# How to set onBackButton listener to an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have a Class A which runs activity via `startActivityForResult` by passing `Intent` to it. In other class, lets say B I get this `Intent` and recreate activity by it. How can I listen events for that activity, e.g. activity which was started for result is running and user pressed "back" button so I want to do some action.
How can I do this?
Thank you on advance.

Activity in which i recreate instance of object is not derived from Activity class. It is just ACTIVITY. So I have only object. is there any way to do such stuff with instance of class but not a class?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should override the method : [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) of the `Activity` class.

Answer (score 4):

In the activity, where you want to act on "back" button, simply override `onKeyDown` (or `onKeyUp`) method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //do whatever you need for the hardware 'back' button
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Keep in mind that if you want the "back" key to still end your activity, then you'll need to include

```
setResult(result);    //if you want to pass a result to activity A
finish();
```

somewhere in that conditional before `return true;`

Answer (score 1):

You can override [`onDestroy`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) and put the code there.

Another possibility (and may fit your needs better) is to override [`onBackPressed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29).

Comment: Wouldn't this be called by the system if the Activity is being destroyed, for example, due to out-of-memory?  I'm not sure this is what OP is after.

Comment: You have a point, although I think that in general it is better to follow the activity life cycle and not be bound to keys.

Comment: Well, that depends what the requirements are.  In one of my apps, I have an activity, whose view is changing based on user action.  When the "back" key is pressed, I either restore the original state (if I'm in the changed state) or finish the activity.  In this case, the lifecycle isn't going to help me.